# Need Suggestions on Migrating from SVN to GIT

Tags: git, svn

I'm trying to migrate one of our project from SVN to GIT and I'm using Git Bash version - 1.8.4 on a windows machine.

I have 3 concerns here.

1.It is a **Non-standard structure of SVNREPO** as

svn_Repository

```
-Trunk
-Branches
-Tags
-Release(Additional folder)
```

I'm trying to clone using the below command

git svn clone SVNURL --authors-file=authors.txt --no-metadata -s RepoName.

So is it the exact command to be used to clone Non-standard SVNREPO .

2.And when ever I try to clone using the above command it throws error

fatal: Unable to create 'f:/..../..../.git/svn/refs/remotes/tags/V1.2.1.1020 Alpha 3 /index.lock': No such file or directory
read-tree c987c7ec5575b4aa8f42c3ec7807dff5cebe565f: command returned error: 128

And If I try to create index.lock manually it gives other error

Found possible branch point: //SVNURL/branches/1.2.x => httpSVNURL/tags/V1.2.1.1020%20Alpha%203%20, 85158
Use of uninitialized value in substitution (s///) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/Gi
t/SVN.pm line 106.

So,Could any one suggest me the correct steps to do it.

Comment: You can try to use `git svn init...` and `git svn fetch -r` to fetch only parts of the history.

Comment: Thanks @Rudi for the immediate response.                                                    
But I need to clone it with complete history and I was facing index.lock and perl issues .
I can't figure it out and If possible , Need some more suggestions on this.

Comment: You can fetch multiple intervals afterwards. Say you have 100 revisions, you can run `git svn fetch -r20`, `git svn fetch -r40`, `git svn fetch -r60`, `git svn fetch -r80` and `git svn fetch -r100` to fetch the whole history with 5 independend steps.

Comment: What is your SVN Version ? See: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/309062/git-svn-clone-branches-tags-with-whitespaces-not-supported

Comment: I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.8.5, Subversion 1.8.8 and GitBash version 1.8.4